# Como optimizar un clase para que me devuelva una lista o una entidad

Tags: c#

Estimados Todos.

Soy nuevo en la plataforma c# estoy desarrollando una aplicación en 3 capas, en la capa lógica de negocio realizo una consulta de clientes la cual me trae una lista y lo lleno un datagridview según un criterio de búsqueda, ejemplos por nombres o por numero de identificación o por código del cliente o incluso por direcciones.

Aqui el codigo

```
    public List<ECliente> GetListClientes(string Criterio)
    {
        List<ECliente> lista = new List<ECliente>();
        IDataReader reader = null;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("SELECT");
        sb.Append(" CLI.CLI_CODIGO ");
        sb.Append(", CLI.CLI_NOMBRE");
        sb.Append(", CLI.CLI_RUC");
        ...
        ...
        ...
        sb.Append(", CLI.TP_CODIGO ");
        sb.Append("FROM CLIENTES CLI, GRUPOS GRU ");
        sb.Append("WHERE CLI.GRU_CODIGO = GRU.GRU_CODIGO ");
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Criterio))
        {
            // Todos los Clientes
        }
        else
        {
            sb.Append(Criterio);
        }



        try
        {
            conexion.Open();

            reader = conexion.ExecuteReader(CommandType.Text, sb.ToString());

            while (reader.Read())
            {

                ECliente eCliente = new ECliente();
                eCliente.CLI_CODIGO = (Int32)reader["CLI_CODIGO"];
                eCliente.CLI_NOMBRE = reader["CLI_NOMBRE"].ToString().Trim();
                eCliente.CLI_RUC = reader["CLI_RUC"].ToString().Trim();
                eCliente.CLI_DIRECCION = reader["CLI_DIRECCION"].ToString().Trim();
                eCliente.CLI_TELEFONO = reader["CLI_TELEFONO"].ToString().Trim();
                eCliente.CLI_FAX = reader["CLI_FAX"].ToString().Trim();
                eCliente.CLI_CELULAR = reader["CLI_CELULAR"].ToString().Trim();
                eCliente.CLI_EMAIL = reader["CLI_EMAIL"].ToString().Trim();
                if (reader["CLI_FCH_NACIM"]!=DBNull.Value)
                {
                    eCliente.CLI_FCH_NACIM = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["CLI_FCH_NACIM"]);
                };

                EGrupo eGrupo = new EGrupo();
                eGrupo = nGrupo.GetGrupo(eCliente.GRU_CODIGO);
                eCliente.GRUPO = eGrupo;

                lista.Add(eCliente);

            }
            reader.Close();
            return lista;
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            conexion.Close();
        }

    }
```

como se puede observar me trae una lista de entidades.

Ahora como hago para que me retorne una clase que me devuelva una entidad
Ejm:

```
    public ECliente GetCliente(int Codigo) {...}
```

sin tener que volver a programar el SQL y el llenado del datareader a la clase para optimizar el código.

Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Por favor **No hagas eso**. Al pasar el criterio como `string` pueden haber cientos de problemas, incluyendo SQL Injection. ¿Es realmente necesario que la condición sea dinámica de esa manera?

Comment: Ye te recomendaria que investigues sobre Entity Framework, este es un ORM que en resumidas cuentas, hace el mapeo de base de datos a entidades automaticamente, y tu codigo sera mas conciso y mantenible.

Comment: Gracias investigare un poco mas sobre entity framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes dos formas de hacerlo.

Una es controlando desde donde llames a tu GetListClientes. Esto sólo si estás seguro de que siempre te retornará 1 registro.

```
public ECliente CallCliente(string cedula)
{
   return GetListClientes(cedula)[0];
}

public List<ECliente> CallClientes()
{
  return GetListClientes(string.Empty);
}
```

De esta forma, reutilizas código y lo manejas desde un solo método.

La otra posibilidad, es necesariamente crear otro método que sólo retorne un ECliente y no un List. Te aconsejo la primera opción.

Finalmente, me di la libertad de hacer unos pequeños retoques a tu código

```
public List<ECliente> GetListClientes(string criterio)
    {
        List<ECliente> lista = new List<ECliente>();
        string consulta = "SELECT CLI.CLI_CODIGO, CLI.CLI_NOMBRE... FROM ... WHERE 1=1 "
        /*Suponiendo que tienes un objeto tipo SqlCommand que se llame command*/
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(criterio))
        {
            consulta += " AND CAMPO_BUSQUEDA = @CRITERIO";
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue(@CRITERIO, criterio);
        }
        try
        {
            conexion.Open();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(command.ExecuteReader());    
            foreach (DataRow a in dt.Rows)
            {    
                ECliente eCliente = new ECliente();
                eCliente.CLI_CODIGO = (Int32)a["CLI_CODIGO"];
                eCliente.CLI_NOMBRE = a["CLI_NOMBRE"].ToString().Trim();
                eCliente.CLI_RUC = a["CLI_RUC"].ToString().Trim();
                eCliente.CLI_DIRECCION = a["CLI_DIRECCION"].ToString().Trim();
                eCliente.CLI_TELEFONO = a["CLI_TELEFONO"].ToString().Trim();
                eCliente.CLI_FAX = a["CLI_FAX"].ToString().Trim();
                eCliente.CLI_CELULAR = a["CLI_CELULAR"].ToString().Trim();
                eCliente.CLI_EMAIL = a["CLI_EMAIL"].ToString().Trim();
                if (reader["CLI_FCH_NACIM"]!=DBNull.Value)
                {
                    eCliente.CLI_FCH_NACIM = Convert.ToDateTime(a["CLI_FCH_NACIM"]);
                };

                EGrupo eGrupo = new EGrupo();
                eGrupo = nGrupo.GetGrupo(eCliente.GRU_CODIGO);
                eCliente.GRUPO = eGrupo;    
                lista.Add(eCliente);    
            }
            return lista;
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            conexion.Close();
        }    
    }
```

Espero te sirva, saludos!

Comment: Gracias Gonzalo por tu ayuda, me quedo claro

Comment: Podrías marcar la respuesta como la aceptada por favor. Gracias!